# How can I execute concurrently the same block of code for 2 type of exchange, but consistently for the same type of exchange?

Tags: concurrency, apache-camel

I have 2 type of tasks/events (type_A and type_B) in my java/camel application, witch can be executed concurrently using the same block of code. But at the same time each type of this tasks should be executed consistently (if type_A is executing right now, the next task of type_A should wait).

In other words I want to write camel route, witch will be an analogy for this code:

```
synchronized(taksType.intern()){
   ..
   // taksType - String literal like "type_A" or "type_B"
   // some operations
   ...
}
```

I think camel route should look like this, but I have no idea, how I can assign one thread (in thread pool) for task of concrete type.

```
from("direct:eventSource")
    .process(...)
    .split(splitByType()).threads(2 ,2 ,"threadName")
    .to("direct:concurrentBlock")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in-memory queues via seda, and have the splitter send to seda:a or seda:b. And then you can have two routes where one starts from seda:a and another from seda:b. The they run in parallel, but only 1 thread for A and 1 thread for B